# CHtmlView: How to get data on click?

Tags: javascript, html, mfc

I have an MFC application that uses `CHtmlView`. It displays some text in html format from some temp html file. Is it possible to handle mouse click on a paragraph to send some data to the program? I understand that javascript can be used to handle click, but how to pass the data from javascript function to the application??
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to cleanly call the containing application from within the Javascript of the HTML page. At the Javascript level the MSHTML interface that is doing the actual work of the CHtmlView provides an "external" object that acts as a way back to the calling application.

Suppose we want to add a method "someCall()" that can be called from Javascript, and that the method takes a string as an argument. In JavaScript we would call it with something like

```
external.someCall("An example string");
```

In the MFC application, we need to write a CCmdTarget derived object to act as the implementation of the "external" object as a dispatch-based COM object, something like:

```
class TestExternal : public CCmdTarget
{
public:
  TestExternal()
  {
    EnableAutomation();
  }

  void SomeCall(LPCWSTR str)
  {
    // This is where we get called when the Javascript runs...
  }

private:
  DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()
};

BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(TestExternal,CCmdTarget)
  DISP_FUNCTION(TestExternal,"someCall",SomeCall,VT_EMPTY,VTS_WBSTR)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

To tie this implementation of "external" with the HTML view, in a class derived from CHtmlView you need to over-ride OnGetExternal() and to point it to an instance of TestExternal that lives at least as long as the CHtmlView:

```
class TestHtmlView : public CHtmlView
{
  // Usual implementation stuff goes here...

public:
  HRESULT OnGetExternal(LPDISPATCH *lppDispatch)
  {
    *lppDispatch = m_external.GetIDispatch(TRUE);
    return S_OK;
  }

private:
  TestExternal m_external;
};
```

Note that I haven't actually tested this, but it seems about right from memory ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also found another solution here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_27074319.html?cid=748#a35898616. This definitely works. I am not sure what is better.

Comment: It's hard to answer that question, as following that link just leads me to a page where those nice expert-sex-change people ask me to sign up with my credit card. No thank you :-)

Comment: Here is the main part: You use MFC event handlers. For example, when you click on the paragraph, you have JavaScript redirect the page to an invalid URL, say, http://MY_URL. You then handle the OnBeforeNavigate2event in your CHtmlView and query for the URL being navigated to: if it contains MY_URL, you know that your paragraph was clicked on, so you need to handle it in whatever way you see fit. Any other URL that does not contain MY_URL can just be handled normally. You can even add additional "arguments" onto MY_URL that you can then parse off

Comment: It sounds like the initial question wasn't completely clear: you talk about clicking on a paragraph, but it sounds (from the solution) that you actually mean clicking on a link (not the same thing!) If all you want to do is catch a link, OnBeforeNavigate2() would work.

Comment: No, actually I am clicking on a paragraph that has onClick=myJavascriptfunction(this), thus catching the click.